# Error: An error was thrown when attempting to render log messages via LogBox

Tags: react-native, logging, expo, try-catch

I'm working on an app and everything is working fine, then I began to get this error when I log things out from try-catch block

```
Error: An error was thrown when attempting to render log messages via LogBox.
```

Please what could cause this?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

i had the same issue and i spend all most two days to find any solution and in the end i find their is one console.log() statement which is logging the entire redux store, so as soon as i removed the console statement error removed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31295326)